# RegexKitLite in IOS5

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, ios5, nsstring

I need RegexKitlite in my App as a part of String validation.
Have also added libicucore.A.dylib .
Currently working with xcode 4.2,Base sdk iOS 5.0,Apple LLVM compiler 3.0,architechture armv7.
Adding the regexkit folder to my app, causes too many errors like
 Automatic Reference Counting Errors ,
 Cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'CFStringRef' etc

Please help;where have I gone wrong.

Answer (score 34):

You can also disable the ARC for the RegexKitLite only by adding a flag:

select the project -> YOUR Target -> on the Tab the "Build Phases" and open the "Compile Sources" and add for "RegexKitLite.m" the flag "-fno-objc-arc".

Update:
If you get:

Undefined symbols:
"_uregex_reset", referenced from:
_rkl_splitArray in RegexKitLite.o
_rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
"_uregex_appendTail", referenced from:.......

Then you need to add in the Tab "Build Settings" -> "Linking" -> "Other Linker Flags" the "-licucore"

Comment: In modern times, you should go to Link Binary with Libraries and add "libicucore.dylib"

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  Regexkit just hasn't been updated to iOS 5 yet.  The big change in iOS 5 is there are no longer retains, releases, or autoreleases.  Every memory thing is automatic like Java.  (Except that it happens at compile time instead of run time.  So it's conceptually like Java.  Mostly.)

Anyway, instead of waiting for Regexkit to update you can use NSRegularExpression.  Using Apple stuff is also future-proof since they keep their own stuff updated version to version.

Good luck!

Comment: it isn't like java ;) like... not at all

Answer (score 0):

CBGraham is right. Alternatively, you could disable automatic reference counting (Project > Build settings > search for 'automatic reference counting').

You will obviously have to do manual reference counting, but RegexKitLite should build now...

Answer (score 0):

I replaced RegexKitLite with there two methods.

String Results:

```
+(NSString*) regExString: (NSString *) pattern withString: (NSString *) searchedString {
    NSError  *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:searchedString options:0 range:  NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length])];
    if ([searchedString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]) {
        return [searchedString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
    } else {
        return @"";
    }
}
```

Array of Results:

```
+(NSArray *) regExArray:(NSString *) pattern withString: (NSString *) searchedString {
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range: NSMakeRange(0, searchedString.length)];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
        NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        NSString *numString = [searchedString substringWithRange:matchRange];
        [result addObject:numString];

        for (int i=1;i < (int)match.numberOfRanges;i++) {
            NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
            @try {
                NSString *numString = [searchedString substringWithRange:range];
                [result addObject:numString];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                [result addObject:[NSNull null]];
            }
        }
       [results addObject:result];
   }
   return results;
}
```